# MS Access error: The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

So I'm trying to run an aggregation query in a MS Access 2007-2010 database that groups by values compared across a few fields in 2 tables. When I try to run the query, I get the error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add"

```
SELECT * FROM 
orderTable AS a INNER JOIN availableInventory AS b ON (a.sellerID = b.sellerID) AND 
(a.daysofweek = b.daysofweek) AND (a.supplierID = b.supplierID);
```

this error doesn't appear when I remove one of the constraints. Is this a MS Access limitation?

table a has ~3000 rows and table b has ~6000 rows if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `select *`?  It looks like one of your tables has a `memo` field which is returning a large amount of data.  Instead try to list the fields of your select like this:

```
select a.orderID, b.partno, etc.
```

Or, change your query to use **UniqueValues** = **No**

See also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896950