# MS Access keeps on breaking my queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I wrote a query in MS Access which I was able to run successfully. However whenever I head back to Design View in MS Access 2010, it kindly corrects it for me into SQL that doesn't even work!

Here is my original SQL (which I ran successfully):

```sql
SELECT [AssetTypeCounts].DELIVERED_IDENTIFIER, 
[AssetTypeCounts].DELIVERED_SOURCE, 
Switch([AssetTypeCounts].TYPES<1,"Missing",
[AssetTypeCounts].TYPES=1,"Correct",[AssetTypeCounts].TYPES>1,"Conflicting") AS STATUS
FROM (
  SELECT DELIVERED_IDENTIFIER, DELIVERED_SOURCE, Sum(IIf(Len(PRODUCTTYPE)>0,1,0)) AS TYPES 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DELIVERED_IDENTIFIER, PRODUCTTYPE, BILLINGCODE, DELIVERED_SOURCE    
    FROM AprilUsageFile) AS "DisctinctAssetIdBySource"
  GROUP BY DELIVERED_IDENTIFIER, DELIVERED_SOURCE 
)  AS AssetTypeCounts;
```

After I go back to Design View I get an error:

> The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data.

I didn't even get a chance to edit the query.

Why does Access keep changing my query?

Can I disable features where MS Access is changing my queries?

Comment: Dont open it in View mode, it cannot display it correctly so it breaks. Use SQL view only.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078688/ms-access-error-the-field-is-too-small-to-accept-the-amount-of-data-you-attempt and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896950/error-message-when-you-run-a-query-in-access-the-field-is-too-small-to-accept-the-amount-of-data-you-attempted-to-add

Comment: Access SQL does not use the double quotes identifier. Try removing it with `AS DisctinctAssetIdBySource`.

Answer (score 1):

try to create a new query by printing in immediate window:

```
Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef
Set qDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("NameOfBrokenQuery")
Debug.Print qDef.SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule never open SQL queries in designer mode, because access will always change parts of it and then it will be harder for your to change it.